# How can I find a object from dbcontext with string parameter, not with Find(primary key) function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

Yes, context.Accounts.Find(id) where id is primary key, it does bring me the right account.
But I want to search from context.Accounts with string username, not by primary key.

To be more precise, method:

```
public void Authenticate(string username, password)
{       result = false;
        Accounts test = new Accounts();
        test.User = username;
        Accounts dbEntry = new Accounts();
        dbEntry = context.Accounts_.Find(test.User);

        if (dbEntry.Password == password)
            if(dbEntry.Admin == 1)
              result = true;
        return result;
    }
```

So username is not primary key anymore, how i can find the right one without Find() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
    Accounts test = new Accounts();
    test.User = username;
    Accounts dbEntry = new Accounts();
    dbEntry = context.Accounts_.Find(test.User);
```

with

```
var dbEntry = context.Accounts_.FirstOrDefault(acc => acc.username == username);
```

or whatever the 'Username' is called in your Accounts_

Comment: Do you know anyway to get a list of object with same value?

Comment: @FaizEming use a `Where` clause.  `context.Accounts.Where(x => x.Blah == "blah").ToList()`